# I'm getting undefined when accessing JSON attribute

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using Parse Server, and in the Cloude Code, before save, I want to get a json from an api.

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to get a json, and here's the result of the json formatted:

[image: Json]

This is my code to get the json:

```
var getJSON = function(url, requisicaoAceita, requisicaoFracassou) {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status!=200){
            requisicaoFracassou(xhr.responseText);
        }else{
            requisicaoAceita(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};


getJSON(url,
    function(xhr){
        var resultado = xhr;
        console.log(resultado);
        console.log(resultado.result);
    },

    function(xhr){
        console.log("Error");
    }
);
```

In the first output `console.log(resultado)` I get the result correctly, but in the second `console.log(resultado.result)` i get undefined, why is that?

Thanks :)

Comment: parse the result before using console.log(JSON.parse(resultado).result);

Comment: Worked! Thanks man!

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help-me [Shubham Khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri)

> parse the result before using
>   console.log(JSON.parse(resultado).result);

After doing this, worked!

```
var resultado = JSON.parse(xhr);
console.log(resultado.result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did use [`.responseText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) instead of [`.response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) which would take into account the chosen `responseType`. Your `resultado` is still a JSON string, not an object with a `result` property

Comment: There's no .response property

Comment: Really? `requisicaoAceita(xhr.response);` doesn't work?

Comment: no :( 
Only responseText returns the information. 
I'm using a npm library, can be this the problem?